# Abort While accessing a vector

Tags: c++, vector, cpu

I have written a program which runs

1. Every 20 seconds
2. When specific request to run that piece of code comes.
3. Every 1 min.

1 and 3 in the list above are two different instances and can overlap.

### Program

Signature of the function giving trouble.

```
bool ProcessInfoHandler::getCPUInfo (rsc::ProcInfo &procInfo, bool isThreadCall)
```

I am getting the below mentioned crash after around 3 days of running the program.

```
#2  0x000000000041fdb8 in sn_sig_handler (signum=6, siginfo=0x451a7d80, undocumented=    <value optimized out>) at common/main/sn_proc_main.cpp:109
#3  <signal handler called>
#4  0x00000031d9630265 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x00000031d9631d10 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#6  0x00000031d966a84b in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#7  0x00000031d967230f in _int_free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#8  0x00000031d967276b in free () from /lib64/libc.so.6  
#9  0x00000000004367a5 in deallocate (this=0x66cff0, __position=..., __x=<value optimized out>)
at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/ext/new_allocator.h:94
#10 _M_deallocate (this=0x66cff0, __position=..., __x=<value optimized out>) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:133 
#11 std::vector<cpu_instance_data_t, std::allocator<cpu_instance_data_t> >::_M_insert_aux (this=0x66cff0, __position=..., __x=<value optimized out>)
at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/vector.tcc:299
#12 0x0000000000431f8e in ProcessInfoHandler::getCPUInfo (this=<value optimized out>, procInfo=..., isThreadCall=false)
at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:610
#13 0x00000000004333be in ProcessInfoHandler::getProcessInformation (this=0xc16f9c0, procInfoSeq=..., isThreadCall=false) at processinfohandler.cc:255
```

### My Questions

1. Unlike frame 13, where the file name and line number is given, frame 12 is not given that information. Does this mean that there is a problem with pass by reference of the vector?
2. Any pointers as to how I should proceed to debug this particular stack trace?

The code of `getCPUInfo` can not be given for proprietary reasons. Please suggest if there is a workaround for the same.

Comment: Can you add the code from `ProcessInfoHandler::getCPUInfo` to your question?

Comment: It looks like heap corruption. You either need built-in malloc debug functionality or use valgrind. Given the fact it took 3 days to trigger the problem it may not be easy to reproduce/find.

Comment: Question 1) no, it means exactly what it says: value optimized out. Method may have been inlined. 2) You're dealing with a **double free** (or heap corruption)

Comment: I suggest [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) for finding the location of possible memory errors.

Comment: even if it took 3 days to trigger it, there is a good chance that valgrind will find the problem instantly. give it a shot.

Comment: The for ProcessInfoHandler::getCPUInfo can not be added for proprietary reasons. Sincere aplogies for the same. Can you please suggest a workaround .. ?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, can the vector in getCPUInfo be accessed by two threads concurrently? In that case it looks like that is the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `std::vector<>::_M_insert_aux()` indicates that the vector is being modified in `getCPUInfo` - if this code can be called concurrently (on multiple threads) which is implied by your "list of 3", then you need to have something such as a mutex to synchronize the threads.

`std::vector` is not thread safe.